# How could I iterate through a url using a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have the following url structure

[https://www.website.com/business/[provinceCode]/[city]/[city](https://www.website.com/business/%5BprovinceCode%5D/%5Bcity%5D/%5Bcity) code].html

and have the following dictionary structure:

```
dictionary = {
   provinceCode1: {
       city1: city code 1
   },
   provinceCode2: {
       city2: city code 2
   }
}
```

I would like to iterate through the key, value pairs in order to print a list.  My code as follows:

```
baseURL = 'https://www.website.com/business/'

provinceDictionary = {
    'AB': {
        'calgary': '91',
        'edmonton': '183',
        'canmore': '96'
        },
    
    'BC': {
        'vancouver': '961',
        'surrey': '934',
        'victoria': '966'
    }
}
```

Now this is the part I am unsure, how I can access the following nested parts of the dictionary:

```
for key, value in provinceDictionary:
    page  = str(baseURL) + '/' + (key1-province code-AB) + "/" + (Subkey1-city-calgary) + "/" + (subvalue1-city code-91) + '.html'
    print(page)
```

My expected output would be 'https://www.website.com/business/AB/calgary/91.html'

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
baseURL = 'https://www.website.com/business/{}/{}/{}.html'

provinceDictionary = {
    'AB': {
        'calgary': '91',
        'edmonton': '183',
        'canmore': '96'
        },
    
    'BC': {
        'vancouver': '961',
        'surrey': '934',
        'victoria': '966'
    }
}

for province, dct in provinceDictionary.items():
    for city, code in dct.items():
        print(baseURL.format(province, city, code))
```

Output:

```
https://www.website.com/business/AB/calgary/91.html
https://www.website.com/business/AB/edmonton/183.html
https://www.website.com/business/AB/canmore/96.html
https://www.website.com/business/BC/vancouver/961.html
https://www.website.com/business/BC/surrey/934.html
https://www.website.com/business/BC/victoria/966.html
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`baseURL` is already a string.  You don't need to convert it.

```
for key, value in provinceDictionary.items():
    for subkey, subval in key.items():
        print( f"{baseURL}/{key}/{subkey)/(subval).html" )
```

Answer (score 1):

How is this

```py
for k1, v1 in provinceDictionary.items():
    for k2,v2 in v1.items():
        targetUrl = baseURL+'/'.join((k1,k2,v2))+'.html'
```